# layout_aspectRatio on PercentRelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a layout with [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) as the root view:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_aspectRatio="178%">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstImage"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/secondImage"
        app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstImage"
        />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

What I need to do is set a 16:9 aspect ratio on the `PercentRelativeLayout` and then have 2 images (each 50% wide) within, so it looks something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNG2c.png

But when I run the app, the two images don't show up (as if the view doesn't exist).

What should I change to get what I need?

Comment: `app:layout_aspectRatio` is an attribute you apply to the *children* of `PercentRelativeLayout`, not to the `PercentRelativeLayout` itself.

Comment: @ianhanniballake That would make sense. Is there a layout/method of applying an aspect ratio to a parent view (like a RelativeLayout) and have the children adjust according to that?

Comment: You can certainly nest one within another

Answer (score 0):

When using PercentRelativeLayout you need to set width or height so the other is calculate based on the percentage.
Since you set the root height as wrap_content you need to set the children height as wrap_content or a fixed value, and to have a best result it would be a good idea to set a minimum height

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_aspectRatio="178%">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/firstImage"
    app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/secondImage"
    app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstImage" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```